# Refractive index as a harmonic function of y

Tags: mathematical-physics

Given a refractive index of the form $n(y) = n_0 \cos(ky)$ , where $n_0$ and $k$ are positive constants.

Is it possible to determine the trajectory of a ray of light, in the x-y plane, traveling through a medium with such a refractive index?

through my attempts I got the light travel time
$$T = \int \frac{n(y)\sqrt{1+{y^{'}}^{2}}}{c}dx$$

using the relation $v = c/n(y)$

then using the Euler-Lagrange equation we can get
$$F(y,y') - y'F_{y'}(y,y') = const.$$
where $F(y,y')$ is
$$\frac{n(y)\sqrt{1+{y^{'}}^{2}}}{c}$$
but this doesn't seem solvable to me, and I only end up with a difficult polynomial (in terms of $y'$) of degree 6 and coefficients in terms of $n(y)$.

I'm not sure if I'm going wrong somewhere, is this problem solvable analytically?

Any help or hints would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.